# Detail page on a SilverStripe subdomain is redirecting to the root folder

Tags: php, web-hosting, silverstripe

I'm new in SS and I need to moved one website from one web hosting into Godaddy.

Ir order to do that I have installed SS in my local environment in the root folder and everything works smoothly. Then I went to the subdomain and almost everything works well except the detail page. For example:

Home page: http://subdomain.domain.com.au/subdomain/index.php/ - IT WORKS 
Product - Tools page: http://subdomain.domain.com.au/subdomain/index.php/products/tools/ - IT WORKS 
Tools details page: http://subdomain.domain.com.au/tools/show/slp20xp IT DOESN'T WORK.

If I go to this URL : http://subdomain.domain.com.au/subdomain/index.php/products/tools//show/slp20xp The page is there and working fine. Somehow, on the detail page is trying to go one step backward to the root folder. If I moved this page to the root folder everything works fine.

Any idea what I might be missing? I tried different htacces configuration but none of them seems to work.

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files web.config>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>

# This denies access to all yml files, since developers might include sensitive
# information in them. See the docs for work-arounds to serve some yaml files
<Files *.yml>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
RedirectMatch 403 /vendor(/|$)
RedirectMatch 403 /composer\.(json|lock)
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase '/'

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess of the subdomain, try changing `RewriteBase '/'` to `RewriteBase '/subdomain'`

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work as well. Any other idea?